# What is the exact algorithm for Objective-C's built-in rand() function?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, random

If you have a client/server application and you want to duplicate the same series of random numbers that the rand() function produces on the client, but on a server, what is the algorithm/pseudo code?  The client and server would be given the same seed (srand() on the client).

Thank you!

Please note:

- Is this not known?  If so, please state
- Can it be reverse engineered?  If so, please post, unless any license agreements would prevent you from doing so.  In other words, don't do anything illegal
- I am not interested in design suggestions for the client/server application
- I understand that there are better and more recent ways to generate rand numbers

Comment: Are you sure *random* numbers is what you need to achieve your greater goals? Because with this you won't be generating anything near *random*: only pre-determined sequences. If you do want *random* numbers, this is not the best approach. If you don't need *random* numbers, why would you use `rand()`?

Comment: @Martinho: `rand()` doesn't provide *random* numbers, it provides a pseudo-random sequence. Which looks to be exactly what the questioner wants (since he's using the same seed in two different places), he's just calling them "random numbers".

Comment: I certainly wouldn't use `rand` for this unless the documentation for both iOS and OSX specifies the exact algorithm, and specifies the same thing. Otherwise there's no reason to suppose that Apple won't change it in some future release of one OS or the other, and your client/server will no longer match. And even if it is documented, it's so easy to write a simple PRNG that I still probably wouldn't risk `rand`.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: You are correct.  I am looking for the same pseudo-random sequence.  Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Yes, I also understood this risk.  Thank you for expressing this concern, it is always good to see it written down for the other users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Apple's Darwin source code, [here is the Mac implementation of `rand()`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-594.9.4/stdlib/rand-fbsd.c), which should be the same as the one used on iOS.  [Here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-594.9.4/stdlib/random-fbsd.c) also is the `random()` implementation.  They both appear to be drawn from FreeBSD.

Answer (score 1):

Most C compilers I've seen use a [linear congruential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) random number generators for their rand() function. You don't need to reverse engineer it: it's open source.

BTW if this is the basis of some sort of encryption/security system. It's a *really* bad idea.

Comment: Ferruccio, Thank you for your answer.  This is not for an encryption/security system -- I agree, that would be a horrible idea.  I am excited to look into "linear congruential random number generators" further.